# Converting timestamps to dates in Google sheet script

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a code that targets a column with dates and I would like to get the dates and compare it to the current date so that I can get the difference between the two.

I ran into a problem I am having trouble solving. It seems that when I used .getValues in my range, it placed each timestamp in an array then those arrays in another array. Like this: [[(new Date(1539619200000))], [(new Date(1540396800000))], [(new Date(1540828800000))]]

I would like to place all the values in 1 array only so I can start solving how to convert the timestamps in to normal dates. I am also a beginner with this so I am sorry if this seems like an basic question.

```
function datesincolumn() //collects only the date values in range
{

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //will identify last row with any data 
 entered
 var range = sheet.getRange('D2:D' + lastRow); //will get range of cells 
 with data present
 var dates = range.getValues();//gets all values in the range
 var CurrentDate = new Date();
 var timestamps = [];

 for (i = 0; i <= dates.length; i++)
 {
   if (dates[i] >= i)
   {
     timestamps.push(dates[i]);
   }

 }

  Logger.log(dates);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.getValues()`, you will *always* get a 2-dimensional array. The outer array represents the row, and the inner array represents the columns. Since you're only getting one column, you can simply append `[0]` to your `dates[i]`.

```
function datesincolumn() { //collects only the date values in range  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //will identify last row with any data entered
  var range = sheet.getRange('D2:D' + lastRow); //will get range of cells with data present
  var dates = range.getValues();//gets all values in the range
  var CurrentDate = new Date();
  var timestamps = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= dates.length; i++) {
    var date = dates[i][0];
    if (date >= i)
      timestamps.push(date);
  }
  Logger.log(dates);
}
```